# Anime movie played on Adult Swim, guy gets enrolled in a mech program to fight against blue crystals

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, mecha

A few years ago I saw an anime movie on Adult Swim.

This movie began with a guy walking into an empty city with a photo of a girl with an arrow pointing towards her boobs. Later in the movie he gets enrolled in this mech program to save the city from giant blue crystals that bleed red and were trying to destroy the city.

He later bonds with a girl who had a terrible back story and saves the town.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the time frame?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182258/90s-manga-anime-about-pilots-merged-into-the-backs-of-gundam-like-suits/182296

Answer (score 14):

This might not be it, but your description reminds me of the seminal anime *Neon Genesis Evangelion*. Or more likely, *Rebuild of Evangelion*, a series of movies (three so far, with a fourth in development hell) that retell the original story with a few changes.

> This movie began with a guy walking into an empty city with a photo of a girl with an arrow pointing towards her boobs

The protagonist, Shinji Ikari, spends the series living with a woman named Misato who has a not-insignificant bust. She sends him a postcard so he'll recognise her.

[image: young woman on a postcard, wearing a bikini]

> Later in the movie he gets enrolled in this mech program

Shinji does indeed "get in the fricking robot", as the saying goes.

> to save the city from giant blue crystals the bleed red and were trying to destroy the city

The antagonists of *Neon Genesis Evangelion* are the Angels, bizarre alien entities that are trying to destroy the planet. One of them, Ramiel, is a giant blue screaming octahedron.

[image: *SCREAMS GEOMETRICALLY*]

> He later bonds with a girl who had a terrible back story

That could be literally any of the girls in *Neon Genesis Evangelion*. Pretty much all of them have terrible backstories.

Comment: I am almost certain you are correct @F1Krazy.  More secifically, it is the remake/remade version (the one that they still have not finished) and not the original series.

Comment: You should watch it! The original _Neon Genesis Evangelion_ series is a tad drawn out (which _Rebuild_ probably tries to fix), but it's still great, and the ending movie _End of Evangelion_ is fantastic.

Comment: By the way, the scene with the photo does happen. [Here's the photo of Misato with the arrow pointing at her cleavage](http://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7mo8mLT6g1qamhyd.jpg), and [here's Shinji holding it](https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/evangelion/images/9/92/Shinji_Ikari.png).

Comment: The annotation is "*note the cleavage!!*"

Comment: @Valorum: [You learned that in a month and a half?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161726/are-there-any-changes-in-the-japanese-edition-of-harry-potter#comment427195_161726)

Comment: Thanks for finding the picture of Misato, guys! I added a picture of Ramiel as well. Hopefully the OP comes back and sees this answer.

Comment: Wow, I never really thought how creepy it was for a _mid-20 something_ woman to send a postcard of herself, making special mention to notice the cleavage, with a lipstick kiss, to a..what, 15 year old? Yeah, fine, I'm sure it's a "deconstruction of whatever," but still.