# 90s manga/anime about pilots merged into the backs of Gundam like suits

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've been trying to remember an anime/manga I used to watch when I was a kid. The parts I remember are:

- Metal suits (like Gundam sing but not) that the pilots merged into the backs of these machines
- That they were in space but crashed on earth and one of their enemies  were (excuse this) but what I can only describe as space spiders.
- I know that when the people merged with their robots it was like an embiotic gel/ sack

I would say it was on Cartoon Network in the 90s in the UK and I assume USA. Can you help me remember the name of this anime/manga?

Comment: I first thought of **Spider Riders** but that was made in 25 March, 2006. Is the show that you mention perhaps similar in any way?

Comment: My first thought is "Blue Gender" but that was on Cartoon Network in the early 2000s. What about "Neon Genesis Evangelion"? That aired in the 90s.

Comment: Yamato Takeru maybe, but I don't remember any spiders in that.

Comment: Is _"Gundam sing"_ a typo for [_"Gundam Wing"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam_Wing)?

Answer (score 5):

I think this may be Neon Genesis: Evangeleon.

> Metal suits (like Gundam sing but not) that the pilots merged into the backs of these machines

Yes, the pilots of the Eva’s wear such suits, called Plug Suits, and are housed in a tube (called an Entry Plug) injected into the back of the head of the EVA units.

> That they were in space but crashed on earth and one of their enemies were (excuse this) but what I can only describe as space spiders.

There are shots of lower atmosphere and attacks coming from space. There was the Ninth Angel, Materiel, that lands and looks like a Daddy Longlegs spider. You can read more about it [here](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Matarael)

> I know that when the people merged with their robots it was like an embiotic gel/ sack

Yes, the pilots are suspended in a fluid called LCL fluid which acts as a psychic conductor, making it easier for them to connect with the Eva. In addition, it helps physically protect them from some of the physical stresses.

I’m pretty sure it played on Cartoon Network, but I’m in the US not the UK and won’t swear to it.

Comment: Cartoon Network ran the original Evangelion series, as well as the first two reboot movies

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe can be blue gender

Its a story about a insect developed ad a biological weapon, but went out of control and the humans are living in a space station, they have mechas that would fit in your description.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Gender